# helm error "Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am getting an error in my kubernetes cluster while upgrading my install of `kamus`

```
$ helm --debug upgrade --install soluto/kamus

[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '64252'
[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:64252"
Error: This command needs 2 arguments: release name, chart path
```

Using helm version 2.13.1

This error is also known to be cause by not correctly using `--set` correctly or as intended.

As an example when upgrading my ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx installing as such:

```
 --set "controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz,"controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"=$DNS_LABEL
```

This caused the same error as listed above.

When I removed the quotations it worked as intended.

```
 --set controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path=/healthz,controller.service.annotations.service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name=$DNS_LABEL
```

The error in this case had nothing to do with not correctly setting a release name and or chart. More explanation of --set issues and solutions are below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Helm upgrade](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_upgrade.md) command requires release name and chart path. In your case, you missed release name.

> helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]

`helm --debug upgrade --install kamus soluto/kamus` should work.

Comment: If the helm chart has embeded dependencies then the helm upgrade complains Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: another-simple-chart
helm.go:81: [debug] found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: another-simple-chart.  Is there there a way that the dependencies get updated by the upgrade cmd.  I am using helm-upgrade-from-source in my tekton pipeline. 
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.CheckDependencies

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this error when I do `--set key value` instead of `--set key=value`. The cause was as stupid as the error message.

Comment: Had same issue with:
helm upgrade --install mychartname myrepo/myrelease --set x y

Worked with:
helm upgrade --install mychartname myrepo/myrelease --set x=y

Comment: I made the stupid mistake of not adding --set for each key=value. I can't believe helm is this bad with error message. Super frustrating

Comment: I had the error when one of my gitlab CI vars (used for one of the options in my Helm call) was undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar error too. Turned out that the problem was the values that I've been passing as argument. So take this example:

```
helm upgrade my-release ./mychart --set mypropert.name=${MY_PROP}
```

If the value of `${MY_PROP}` has some whitespace or dash `-` or some other strange characters you get that misleading error. So ensure you enclose your arguments with single-quote:

```
helm upgrade my-release ./mychart --set 'mypropert.name=${MY_PROP}'
```

Comment: Thanks man, it resolved my problem. But in my case taking `'single quotes'` was just taking `{MY_PROP}` as the value itself. `"Double quotes"` worked for me. As someone said, it is pretty stupid bug with even more stupid error message.

Answer (score 2):

Helm upgrade requires both a release name and the chart it references. From the documentation:

`Usage:
  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]`

According to [the documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-upgrade) for the `--install` flag, the command you referenced seems like it should work, but it may be due to differing Helm versions.

`helm install soluto/kamus` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error (too) many times.

**The first thing that should come to your mind is typos in the command**.

For example:

1. If you're passing location of `values.yaml` with `-f <path-to-values.yaml>` you should make sure its in the relevant order related to flags that were passed.
2. If you're passing inline values with the `--set` flag you should make sure that there are no whitespace in the variable assignment like in this case: `--set someVar= $SomeValue.`

Run `helm help upgrade` or `helm help install` to get more information about each commands.

Comment: 3. If you're passing inline values with `--set` flag make sure there are no extra whitespace between `--set` flags. Example:

yaml
          helm upgrade --username usr --password pass \
          releasename \
          repo.url/charts/mychart \
          --install \
          --debug \
          --version v1.0 \
          --set url=app.com \ *no extra whitespace here!*
          --set pullsecret=123

Answer (score 0):

May be this detailed information will be helpful for someone new to this !

**1. My helm files are here (I made changes in values.yaml to upgrade):**

```
controlplane $ pwd
/root/existing2helm
controlplane $ ls
Chart.yaml  charts  templates  values.yaml
```

**2. Listing current releases**

```
controlplane $ helm list 
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
newdeploybyhelm default         2               2021-02-01 00:39:11.596751325 +0000 UTC deployed        existing2helm-0.1.0     1.16.0
```

**3. Finally executing the upgrade command**

```
controlplane $ helm upgrade newdeploybyhelm /root/existing2helm
Release "newdeploybyhelm" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: newdeploybyhelm
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Feb  1 00:48:30 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I add first line parameters

```
--install --create-namespace --wait --atomic
```

to the end of the parameter list again. You may want to check duplicate parameters, or duplicate --install command if you are using a parameter builder.